# Write text between inline exported code and the result of this execution code?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

After some search, i don't found example corresponding to my use case.

Writing a research text, i'm interested to mix source blocks code and text with results using inline mode, for example this simple example :

> Open a terminal and write `git --version` returning  `git version 2.20.1`

`git version 2.20.1` is the simple result of `src_sh[:results value :exports code]{git --version}`. But using this command it's impossible to inject text (here the word `returning`) between the exported code `git --version` and the result of `git -- version` evaluation.

Is it possible to reproduce this behaviour using org-mode and org-babel ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

A short example of behaviour i want to achieve :

Open your terminal and run the command `src_sh[exports:code]{git --version}` which return `$1`, go to `src_sh[exports: code]{cd /home/xxx/myproject}` and count the number of commit using `src_sh[exports:code]{git rev-list --all --count && git branch | wc -l }` returning `$1` commit(s) on `$2` branche(s).

Comment: What version of Org mode are you using? `M-x org-version` will tell you.

Comment: Hi Nick, it's 9.3 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I evaluate the inline src block:

```
src_sh[:results value :exports code]{git --version}
```

I get the following in my org mode buffer:

```
src_sh[:results value :exports code]{git --version} {{{results(=git version 2.24.1=)}}}
```

If you get the same thing, then the only thing you have to do is define a [macro](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html#Macro-Replacement) that will do what you want:

```
#+MACRO: results returning $1
```

When you export, you should get exactly what you want.

**UPDATE**: For your updated question, I would use src code blocks, not inline ones, but then call them inline. This is not quite what you want, but it is close:

```
#+MACRO: results $1

* Instructions

Open your terminal and run the command =git --version= which returns
call_gitversion[:exports results](), =cd /home/nick/emacs/emacs= and
count the number of commits using =git rev-list --all --count && git
branch | wc -l= returning call_ncommits[:exports results]() commit(s)
on call_nbranches[:exports results]() branch(es).


* Code                                                    :noexport:
#+name: gitversion
#+begin_src shell :exports none
git --version
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: gitversion
: git version 2.24.1

#+name: ncommits
#+begin_src shell :exports none
cd /home/nick/src/emacs/emacs
git rev-list --all --count
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: ncommits
: 145317

#+name: nbranches
#+begin_src shell :exports none
cd /home/nick/src/emacs/emacs
git branch | wc -l
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: nbranches
: 2
```

And this was done in a hurry: caveat emptor.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @NickD, it works, but syntax is weird if you need to add cut your long text with `#+Macro` which each time start on a new line, do you think there is a way to simplify/generify this syntax ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying: maybe edit your question and add an example?

Comment: I update with an example of readable syntax i'm interested to obtain